# How do I interpret GAMESS thermochemistry output?

Tags: computational-chemistry

In GAMESS's thermochemistry output, which numbers mean what?
The [gaussian docs](http://gaussian.com/thermo/) have a nice description of how to use thermochemistry data, but for gaussian's output. This appears to be different, eg, it mentions thermal corrections to energy, enthalpy, and Gibbs free energy, but GAMESS outputs only one, vibrational, thermal correction.

Example output:

```
 USING IDEAL GAS, RIGID ROTOR, HARMONIC NORMAL MODE APPROXIMATIONS.
 P=  1.01325E+05 PASCAL.
 ALL FREQUENCIES ARE SCALED BY   1.00000
 THE MOMENTS OF INERTIA ARE (IN AMU*BOHR**2)
              0.00000            35.04363            35.04363
 THE ROTATIONAL SYMMETRY NUMBER IS  2.0
 THE ROTATIONAL CONSTANTS ARE (IN GHZ)
      0.00000    51.45266    51.45266
      6 -      6 VIBRATIONAL MODES ARE USED IN THERMOCHEMISTRY.
 THE HARMONIC ZERO POINT ENERGY IS (SCALED BY   1.000)
        0.000110 HARTREE/MOLECULE       24.044128 CM**-1/MOLECULE 
        0.068746 KCAL/MOL                0.287632 KJ/MOL

               Q               LN Q
 ELEC.     1.00000E+00       0.000000
 TRANS.    1.12480E+05      11.630533
 ROT.      6.03147E+01       4.099576
 VIB.      4.82855E+00       1.574546
 TOT.      3.27579E+07      17.304656

              E         H         G         CV        CP        S
           KJ/MOL    KJ/MOL    KJ/MOL   J/MOL-K   J/MOL-K   J/MOL-K
 ELEC.      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
 TRANS.     3.718     6.197   -28.831    12.472    20.786   117.487
 ROT.       2.479     2.479   -10.163     8.314     8.314    42.400
 VIB.       2.490     2.490    -3.616     8.277     8.277    20.478
 TOTAL      8.687    11.166   -42.610    29.063    37.378   180.365
 VIB. THERMAL CORRECTION E(T)-E(0) = H(T)-H(0) =      2202.424 J/MOL

              E         H         G         CV        CP        S
         KCAL/MOL  KCAL/MOL  KCAL/MOL CAL/MOL-K CAL/MOL-K CAL/MOL-K
 ELEC.      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
 TRANS.     0.889     1.481    -6.891     2.981     4.968    28.080
 ROT.       0.592     0.592    -2.429     1.987     1.987    10.134
 VIB.       0.595     0.595    -0.864     1.978     1.978     4.894
 TOTAL      2.076     2.669   -10.184     6.946     8.933    43.108
 VIB. THERMAL CORRECTION E(T)-E(0) = H(T)-H(0) =       526.392 CAL/MOL
```

Comment: Is this your GAMMES output? What exactly is the problem? I see "E", "H", "G", S", which are energy, enthalpy, Gibbs free energy, and entropy. I can show many examples here at the Chemistry SE, where questions have been closed due to being about a specific program (like GAMMES). Your question might be suited for a dedicated Stack Exchange just for computational material science. You might like to help support the motion to make this stack exchange: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling

Comment: @user1271772 So G - TOTAL is the Gibbs free energy 298K? Or 0K?

Comment: From the GAMESS manual supplied by the Gordon Group: "TEMP = an array of up to ten temperatures at which the thermochemistry should be printed out. The default is a single temperature, 298.15 K. To use absolute zero, input 0.001 degrees." So unless you have supplied a temperature, it would be 298.15 K.

Comment: So does it include the electronic energy, or do I have to add that? To be more precise, are these numbers that I can subtract between two runs to get the ∆G?

Comment: @Dan The electronic energy, as determined by the SCF (or what have you) is not included because 1) The $G$ etc. are called "corrections" 2) The total energy of the SCF is much higher than 0.5 kcal/mol. Note that it is most likely given in units of hartree.